# Insert fails on Code First whith non-identity id key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I have defined a model class with an ID column set as [Key], on an existing database table. the table has the field defined as primary key, int, not null. It is NOT and identity column.

When creating a new record in code, I am setting the ID column (to an unique value) in code before calling the SaveChanges() method.

The method returns with the error:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'xxx_id', table
>   'xxx.dbo.xxxxxx'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The
>   statement has been terminated.

It seems that EF assumes that the ID column is an Identity column and therefore doesn't pass the ID in the SQL call to the database.

Is there a way to define the ID column to tell EF that is it not an Identity column and to pass the value in the SQL call

Answer (score 9):

You need to specify the DatabaseGeneratedOption for the property.  In this case, the DatabaseGeneratedOption should be None.

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.databasegeneratedoption%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

I have usually done this with fluent coniguration like:

```
Property(p => p.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

.. but it looks like this can also be specified with an attribute. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.databasegeneratedoption%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

Comment: I have the same issues and I've posted the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45150890/table-not-incrementing-after-an-insert-in-asp-net-mvc/45153161?noredirect=1#comment77324329_45153161