# Table not incrementing after an insert in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC project. I have created the various models and the viewmodels to use in my project. I have also seeded my database table with seed data but upon implementing the registration view, I tested the form but was getting 0 as the value inserted into the Id portion of the database table. I truncated the tables and did a fresh new insert I still had same error.

Below is the model for the user table

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string RefIndicator { get; set; }
    public Team TeamCategory { get; set; }
    public byte TeamId { get; set; }
    public bool IsRegistered { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRegistered { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
    public UserRoles UserRoles { get; set; }
    public byte UserRolesId { get; set; }
}
```

and below is the  viewModel I created for the Team Model property  I needed to use in my view

```
public class RegisterFormViewModel
{
    public User Users { get; set; }
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Team> Teams { get; set; }
    public byte TeamId { get; set; }
    public string RefIndicator { get; set; }
    public bool IsRegistered { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRegistered { get; set; }
    public byte UserRolesId { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the register action to the userController to initialize the values for the Register view

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var AppUser = User.Identity.Name.Substring(5);
    var AppUserEmail = AppUser + "@nlng.com";
    int index = AppUser.IndexOf('.');
    var FirstName = AppUser.Substring(0, index);
    var LastName = AppUser.Substring(index + 1);
    var IsRegistered = true;
    var UserRolesId = 1;
    var DateRegistered = HttpContext.Timestamp;

    var teams = _context.Team.ToList();

    var viewModel = new RegisterFormViewModel{
        Email = AppUserEmail,
        FirstName = FirstName,
        LastName = LastName,
        Teams = _context.Team.ToList(),
        IsRegistered = IsRegistered,
        UserRolesId = (byte)UserRolesId,
        DateRegistered = DateRegistered               
    };

    return View("Register", viewModel);
}
```

And finally here is the associated view for the registration page

```
@model eLeave.ViewModel.RegisterFormViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>User Registration</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "User"))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(r=>r.FirstName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.FirstName, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(r => r.LastName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.LastName, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(r => r.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = true })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(r => r.TeamId)
        @Html.DropDownListFor(r => r.TeamId, new SelectList(Model.Teams, "Id", "TeamName"), "Select your Team", new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(r => r.RefIndicator)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(r => r.RefIndicator, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>

    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsRegistered)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.DateRegistered)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserRolesId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    }
```

Finally here's the save action of the userController

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Save(User user)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var viewModel = new RegisterFormViewModel
        {
            Users = user,
            Teams = _context.Team.ToList()
        };

        return View("Register", viewModel);
    }

    if (user.Id == 0)
    {
        _context.User.Add(user);
    }
    else
    {
        var usersInDb = _context.User.Single(m => m.Id == user.Id);
        usersInDb.FirstName = user.FirstName;
        usersInDb.LastName = user.LastName;
        usersInDb.TeamCategory = user.TeamCategory;
        usersInDb.RefIndicator = user.RefIndicator;
        usersInDb.UserRoles = user.UserRoles;
        usersInDb.IsRegistered = user.IsRegistered;
        usersInDb.Email = user.Email;
        usersInDb.DateRegistered = user.DateRegistered;
    }

    _context.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
}
```

The Save Action basically does two things...It saves a new form and it's also used for updating data.

Would appreciate if the bugs in my code can be fished out.

Comment: I don't think this is the cause, but the `Id` of your `User` is of type `byte`, maybe you should use `Guid` (aka UUID) or a string containing a guid representation (or even an `int`). Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Did you actually define autoincrement on your tables? because I don't see anything that would actually cause an autoincrement behavior..

Comment: I use EF code first approach to create and seed data into the table

Comment: @Alisson yes I'm using entity frame work

Comment: @Alisson yes I'm using entity frame work

Answer (score 1):

Form what I understand, you need to make ID as auto incremented value.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string RefIndicator { get; set; }
    public Team TeamCategory { get; set; }
    public byte TeamId { get; set; }
    public bool IsRegistered { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateRegistered { get; set; }
    public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
    public UserRoles UserRoles { get; set; }
    public byte UserRolesId { get; set; }
}
```

I don't think it will work with `byte`, but you can use `int` for sure.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{        
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(a => a.Id).HasKey(b => b.Id);
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(a => a.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution... this time around the Id value was null so it's not working.

Comment: Because not just user table needs to change, plus all those changes need to be migrated into database.

Comment: Check database in SQL manager if it got incremented flag. If not look on fluent api above.

Comment: Actually, as I saw in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202203/using-byte-as-the-primary-key-datatype), byte can be used as Identity as well.

Comment: @Ssheverdin I'm using the local database that came with the visual studio 2013 installation. How I'm I to check database manager there? Once my application is completed, I'll deploy to the server.

Comment: @Ssheverdin : Do I need to add the extra code above to the model as well?

Comment: @Guzzyman At visual studio panel go: View-Server Explorer, window will open Data Connection-DbName-Table- R. click on table "Table definition" to open VS SQL manager

Comment: @Guzzyman Watch this video on how to work with Code First, second part of video on how to push migrations to DB, it is like saving structure changes to DB. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HbDOhCjjxSY

Comment: @Ssheverdin: I already know how to push migrations to DB. I have done all that for my models and have also seeded them with data. My question here is that the form interface I designed for entering data into the database is entering 0 in the ID column.

Comment: @Guzzyman Check if changes are really get pushed. Because if ID always returns 0, then autoinctremented DataAnnotation is not applied, and during pushing generate the script to see what SQL it is pushing, check if rule is there. Maybe there is column conflicts for key in SQL.  [screen with same problem](https://forums.asp.net/t/1992323.aspx?Auto+Increment+Identity+does+not+work+in+Entity+Framework)

Comment: +some docs, http://techfunda.com/howto/121/auto-increment-property-in-model

Comment: @Ssheverdin: Yes...changes are pushed during migration. I check the tables to ensure the data is there with the show table data...how do I check the SQL? Is it not update-database -verbose?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149560/discussion-between-guzzyman-and-ssheverdin).